# Can I always write $\psi(x) = \varphi \circ f(x)$ for bounded, measurable functions $\psi$, $\varphi$ and submersion $f$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Question: Given a **bounded, measurable** function $\psi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and a **submersion** $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, (with $n > m$) can I always find another **bounded, measurable** function $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\psi(x) = \varphi(f(x)) \qquad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n.
$$

> PS: I am happy to relax/change the conditions on $\psi$ and $\varphi$ for this statement to be true. E.g. can be stricter or looser conditions than bounded, measurable, but still somewhat not too restritive.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $f((x_1,x_2))=x_1$ and $\psi:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ be a bounded measurable function such that $\psi(0,1)\neq\psi(0,2)$. Then $f((0,1))=f((0,2))$, thus you always have $\varphi(f((0,1)))=\varphi(f((0,2)))$.